# How to spawn A GameObject during a certain Time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I created a Timer Countdown script. When said time reaches a certain time I want to instantiate and spawn a prefab.

[image: Script on Timer Prefab]

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class TimerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public GameObject PreFab;

    [SerializeField] private Vector3 spawnPosition;
    float x = 0;

    float y = 0;

    float z = 0;

    public float TimeLeft;
    public bool TimerOn = false;

    public Text TimerTxt;

    void Start()
    {
        
        TimerOn = true;
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (TimerOn)
        {
            if (TimeLeft > 0)
            {
                TimeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
                updateTimer(TimeLeft);
                
            }
            else
            {
                //Debug.Log("Time is UP!");
                TimeLeft = 0;
                TimerOn = false;
            }

           

        }
        if (TimeLeft <= 19.40)
        {

            Instantiate(PreFab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity); 
           
        }
    }

    void updateTimer(float currentTime)
    {
        currentTime += 1;

        float minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(currentTime / 60);
        float seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(currentTime % 60);

        TimerTxt.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);
    }
```

Unity keeps saying the prefab has not been assigned but I serialized it and assigned the given prefab. What am I doing wrong? The countdown works fine with no issues.

[image: Error From Unity]

[image: Error From Unity]

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple objects with that script and one of them has no PreFab assigned? Search TimerScript in the hierarchy it will filter only objects with this script

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is definitely due to the sloppy Hierarchy and sound from the object in which this variable is not defined. The following code helps to fix the error in any case and also tells the name of the object that does not have **PreFab**.

```cs
if (TimeLeft <= 19.40)
{
    if (PreFab)
    {
        Instantiate(PreFab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log($"{name} has not assigned PreFab.");
    }
}
```